# Connect Ricoh P311 to SANE

Tags: server, sane

Does anyone know how to connect the scanner Ricoh P311 to SANE on Ubuntu Server? I have tried SANE with the default settings, tried Airscan on SANE, and also went to Ricoh's official website but could't find drivers for Ubuntu/SANE! When i ping to the Scanner's IP, i get 0% package loss!

```
> scanimage -d "net:192.168.31.50" --resolution 300 --mode "Color
No scanners were identified. If you were expecting something different, check that the scanner is plugged in, turned on and detected by the sane-find-scanner tool (if appropriate). Please read the documentation which came with this software (README, FAQ, manpages).
```

Comment: So the hardware is there and getting an IP from somewhere but you need a driver. Did you try Ricoh support to see if they have a suggest?

Comment: I did try that, they only have generic drivers, tha't don't work in this specific model.

Comment: Seems like you may be out of luck then.

Comment: Looks like i am. Thanks for answering anyway!